# Xcode 4 FLTK 1.3.0 undefined architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, architecture, linker, undefined, fltk

> > > Hi, I am using Xcode 4 and trying to set up FLTK 1.3.0 to run Bjarne
> > >       Stroustrup's Chapter 12 FLTK Demo at the end of the chapter. I keep
> > >       getting the following error when compiling, and have no idea where to go.
> > >       I have an idea it might have to do with the linker flags, but I don't know
> > >       what flag to add and where...
> > >
> > > Here's the error:
> > >
> > > Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> > >          "Fl_JPEG_Image::Fl_JPEG_Image(char const*)", referenced from:
> > >              Graph_lib::Image::Image(Point, String,
> > >       Graph_lib::Suffix::Encoding) in Graph.o
> > >          "Fl_GIF_Image::Fl_GIF_Image(char const*)", referenced from:
> > >              Graph_lib::Image::Image(Point, String,
> > >       Graph_lib::Suffix::Encoding) in Graph.o
> > >       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> > >       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> > >       invocation)

Answer (score 3):

Are you passing the linker flags present with `--use-images`? try:

`> fltk-config --use-images --ldflags`

and check the results to make sure you're getting either the system image libs, or the ones optionally built with fltk.

Answer (score 2):

I also found this to be quite useful:

```
fltk-config --compile test.cpp
```

It worked perfectly for me.
For more examples of using fltk-config check out http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/basics.html